save an image to media in post method django
I want to store an image in the media folder and the URL in the image field of the model. In this code, the image is getting directly saved to the model:
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    userimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/', null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    account_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    business = models.ForeignKey('company.Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

The view:
@api_view(['POST']) 
def CreateAcc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data
        password = make_password(data["password"])
        mail = data['mail']
        name = data['name']
        phone = data['phone']
        image = data['image']
        CustomUser.objects.create(email=mail, username=name,phone=phone, password=password,userimage=image )
        return Response(True)

How do I save the image to the media folder?

The correct behaviour should be the image uploaded to settings.MEDIA_ROOT/profile folder while the image url saving to the database table cell userimage.

@ChukwujiobiCanon yes that is exactly what i want to know. How to do that ?

Ensure that you have set settings.MEDIA_ROOT variable and it will be uploaded to settings.MEDIA_ROOT/profile. If this works for you, I’ll write up an answer explaining why it works.

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`
this is from the settings.py

Okay I wasn’t expecting that. What do you mean by ”…the image is getting directly saved to the model”?

it suppose to be saved as 'media/profile/image.jpg', but when am saving it saved as /static/media/image.jpg

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
